# Frequently Needed Business Rule About Security that SharePoint Does Not Provide OOTB

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, security, custom-list

Suppose that i have two lists like this

REGION_LIST [ RegionName(text), RegionResponsibles(multi-select peoplepicker) ]

ISSUES_LIST [Some issue related columns, Region(lookup) ]

Main requirement is that system should only let the related RegionResponsibles to enter issue for that Region, and also in the list view RegionResponsibles should only see the issues for regions which they are member of.

The thing is; i can programmatically create SPGroups and assign people to those groups than do item-level unique permissions for each issue item. BUT; sharepoint has boundaries and limits for lists containing lar number of unique permissioned items.

As my list will probably have large number of items, i am looking for a solution that i dont have to create unique permissions for each item? Does sharepoint offer any other solutions to these kinds of requirements?

I am now thinking of programmatically check if the user is eligible to add/update item for any region in custom Event Receiver and prevent in ItemAdded/ItemUpdated . That is ok for data entry. But what about viewing only the items they are related to?
Any ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, dividing the main list into many lists is not suitable for my case.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases I've encountered, the 'need' to have items secured in the way you describe is often merely a presumed solution to the problem of users sifting through too much data.   Usually creating views tied to a certain field values will suffice.

If the items truly need that level of isolation then you might want to consider putting the issues themselves into separate lists and securing the lists as needed.  You could then use an aggregator web part such as the Content Query for viewing cross-list issues.  This is certainly not an ideal solution but does work in some cases.

Comment: Thanks but, setting up different lists is not suitable for my case.